Windows command not working with node child_process 'spawn' in electronjs
i was trying to run a command inside a spawned command prompt from my electronJs App(using nodeJs) for application update:
        const exeFile = `Setup_3.4.2.exe`;
        const exeFullPath = path.join(targetPath, exeFile);
        log.info("exeFullPath",exeFullPath);
        const command = `timeout /t 8 /nobreak && "${exeFullPath}"`;
        log.info("executing command", command);

        const child = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/C',command], {
          cwd: targetPath,
          detached: true,
          stdio: 'ignore',
        });
        child.unref();
        app.exit(0);
        child.on('error', (err) => {
          console.error('Failed to start process:', err);
        });

        child.on('exit', (code) => {
          console.log(`Process exited with code ${code}`);
        });

The problem here is that the cmd spawns successfully and the countdown happens as well but the exe doesn't open. When i am running the same command on a separately opened cmd it works.
the logs are as follows:
13:22:41.296 > exeFullPath C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\My-App\Setup_3.4.2.exe
13:22:41.298 > executing command timeout /t 8 /nobreak && "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\My-App\Setup_3.4.2.exe"

I am aware that instead of cmd.exe i can directly pass the path to installer but that won't work in my case since a process of my app is running when the installer opens without any delay and hinders the installation as it shows an instance of app is already running, thus i am trying to add delay so that my app can exit meanwhile and the cmd.exe spawns my installer instead.

Typically spawned child processes exit when their parent exits
